# Utilise Visual Studio Theme in Add-In

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, themes, visual-studio-addins

Is it possible to utilise the current Visual Studio theme within an Add-In? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and want to use the dark and light blue colouring of the environment to colour certain controls within my addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a blog named Changing Visual Studio’s Color Palette which references [the Visual Studio UX Guidelines document](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VS2010UX/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2743).

Answer (score 0):

To handle theme in a VS 2012 addin, have a look at this detailed article:

[HOWTO: Get the current theme and detect changing it from a Visual Studio 2012 add-in.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012012.aspx)